# the chrome extension source code is not getting loaded instead the URL which we are appending in webview is getting loaded

Tags: webview, google-chrome-app

In our chrome extension, we are using  as below

```
<webview id="webviewid" src="" autosize="on" appcache="true" cache="true"  indexedDB="true" localStorage="true" webSQL="true" cookies="true" target="_blank" partition="ourExtensionNamepluswidgets"> </webview>
```

we are appending the src URL dynamically by,

```
var wv =  document.getElementById('webviewid');
wv.src =json.url; //json.url will contains src url to be append
```

After chrome updates to version 61,when we get inside the page where we are using "webview", the extension source code is not running instead the URL which we are appending in webview is getting loaded.

I have checked through inspecting the element of page(in developer mode).

while inspecting it is displaying the src url content source codes, it is not displaying the  tag and also the extension html.

Comment: This happened after the chrome version got update to 61.

Comment: I have included the required "<webview>"

Comment: Try to check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45726006/es6-modules-in-chrome-61-extensions), also check in the [updates](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/08/chrome-61-deprecations) page if it is still in scope or already deprecated. This implementation maybe deprecated as this statement from the documentation "For example, consider a page containing <img src='https://evil.com/?. Because the URL has no closing quote, browsers will read to the next quote that occurs and treat the enclosed characters as if it were a single URL."