# use redux in chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, redux

I am trying to develop an extension for Google Chrome by using React and Redux.
My background.js is the following:

```js
import {wrapStore} from 'react-chrome-redux';
import store from './store';
import rootReducer from './reducers'

const store = createStore(rootReducer, {});

wrapStore(store, {
  portName: 'test'
})
```

I have installed with npm all the modules required but when I upload the extension on Chrome I get this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

I have already checked the compatibility of import on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) and my browser's version is the 62nd, so I think I don't need to use Babel.

My manifest.json file is the following:

```js
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Demo React-Chrome extension",
  "description": "This extension shows how to run a React app in a Chrome extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background": {
    "scripts":["back.js"]
    },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "logo_small.png",
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  }
}
```

Does any of you have an idea about this problem?

Comment: I've made a couple of small sites with React and I've made a few Chrome Extensions. I've not tried to put the two together, but what I would do is npm build the React site, making sure that the build file contains the requisites for chrome extension (manifest, background js, image folders etc.), copy the build files / folders to your extension directory, then load the unpacked extension into the browser from that location as per normal.

Comment: I tried to use React + Chrome Extension before, and it worked without any problem (by using npm run build). This is a repo which I forked https://github.com/pierroberto/react-chrome-extension and used as guideline. It works until I try to implement Redux on it

Comment: OK, I can't help with Redux, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you still need to convert your ES6 code to ES5 when working with Chrome extensions :
[ES6 Modules In Google Chrome Extension Development (unexpected token)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36796191/es6-modules-in-google-chrome-extension-development-unexpected-token)

The best resource I found when writing my first Chrome extension with React and Redux is the one from where you got the `react-chrome-redux` npm package :
https://github.com/tshaddix/react-chrome-redux-examples

Examples are very instructive on how to build the extensions and load them unpacked. `gulp` and `webpack` are used in those cases to build the ES5 code that will finally be loaded.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This definitely helps! I found another interesing example here for who is interested https://github.com/thoughtbot/bookmark_saver

Comment: Nice one indeed, I'm bookmarking it, thanks @L.PierRoberto :-)